# How can I duplicate two cells from a column to rows in a particular order

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to duplicate the cells from a column in a certain order. The cells in the column are dates.
As an example:

```
2014-12-16
2014-12-23
2015-1-23
2015-2-03
2015-2-18
2015-3-11
```

My goal is to take the first date cell, copy it into another row in the same spreadsheet and then take the second date cell and copy it next to the first copied cell. Then duplicate the second cell (from the first row) into the first cell of the second row and then take third date cell and put it to the second cell of the second row. The result should look like this:

```
        Column 1    Column 2
Row A   2014-12-16  2014-12-23
Row B   2014-12-23  2015-1-23
Row C   2015-1-23   2015-2-03
```

So the next rows (D and E) in this case should be:

```
2015-2-03   2015-2-18
2015-2-18   2015-3-11
```

I have a lot of cells so I am looking for some efficient way on how to do it.

**What I have tried:**
Trans copy (selected cells are copied into rows from the column). But that does not solve my problem.

Comment: I think it would be much easier to achieve what you want if the whole process was to be moved to another spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a single array formula such as

```
={A1:A5, A2:A6}
```

(assuming the dates you've shown are in the range A1:A6).

If you expect more dates to be added, and don't want to specify the last row, then two separate arrayformulas should be used for two columns: `={A1:A}` and `={A2:A}`.